# choose image from android image gallery - PhoneGap not working

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

For Android in PhoneGap 2.8.0:

I need to get image from phone gallery and need to insert in app...

**My code:**

**HEAD:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<button data-theme="d" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">Browse    Photos</button>

<div id="photos"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**:

```
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

var img = $('<img />');
img.attr('src', imageURI);


img.appendTo('#photos');

}
```

But its not working....how can i do this?

error that i got in console

**file:///android_asser/www/index.html: Uncaught typeerror : cannot read property 'PHOTOLIBRARY' of undefined**

**Uncaught typeerror : [Object Object] has no method 'split' at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js**

after i removed the jquery and jquery-mobile its working... any problem with jQuery with phonegap?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What the error log says?

Comment: Nothing happen when i click on browse photos...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implemented this code...recently..check this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   
var destinationType; 

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() 
{
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}


function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) 
{
    console.log(imageURI);
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) 
{ 
    var imgProfile = document.getElementById('imgProfile');
    imgProfile.src = imageURI;
    if(sessionStorage.isprofileimage==1)
    {
        getLocation();
    }
    movePic(imageURI);
}

function onFail(message) 
{
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function movePic(file)
{ 
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file, resolveOnSuccess, resOnError); 
} 

function resolveOnSuccess(entry)
{ 
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    var newFileName = n + ".jpg";
    var myFolderApp = "MyAppFolder";
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) 
    {      
        fileSys.root.getDirectory( myFolderApp,
                {create:true, exclusive: false},
                function(directory) 
                {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName,  successMove, resOnError);
                },
        resOnError);
    },
    resOnError);
}

function successMove(entry) 
{
    sessionStorage.setItem('imagepath', entry.fullPath);
}

function resOnError(error) 
{
    alert(error.code);
}

function capturePhotoEdit() 
{
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

function getPhoto(source) 
{
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}



</script>
```

**My html**

```
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Gallery!!</button>
```

Comment: i got error like this,
file:///android_asser/www/index.html: Uncaught typeerror : cannot read property 'PHOTOLIBRARY' of undefined

Comment: you will get that if you dont have the **cordova file** ..please check whether you have inserted the **cordova-2.8.0.jar** in the libs folder and **cordova.js** in your www folder in the assets

Comment: ya now working after removed jQuery and mobile jQuery.. Is any problem using jQuery in phonegap?

Comment: Do you get any error in LogCat...if yes post the logcat...and do post the code you have implemented in your question

Comment: @Dhamu you need to place the jquery before the cordova.js command and there should be not be a single error in the coding parenthesis...If this answer was useful upvote and you can accept it too

Comment: this code will allow you to store the photos u capture Directly to the SD card of the device. there is another way of doing this by implementing `Base64ToPNG.js` but i still trying on that

Comment: @Dhamu please open a new question for that..so that you can post your code that you have implemented

Answer (score 0):

try this link i hope it might be help you

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/27/awesome-mobile-image-gallery-web-app/

See the api

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/index.html

and you also try like

if C`amera.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY` or `Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM`, then a photo chooser dialog is shown, from which a photo from the album can be selected.

Comment: Onclick function itself not working onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);"

Comment: Its that correct i inserted js files...
1. JQuery 
2. JQuery Mobile
3. cordova

Answer (score 0):

Hi blow is working code for Camera and gallery.
I use different function for both purpose because using the device capture you can capture the  multiple image .

i hope it will help you.

```
    <select>
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option onclick="GetImage(1)">Camera</option>
    <option onclick="GetImage(2)">Library</option>
    <option onclick="GetImage(3)">Album</option>
    </select>


    //// fuction to select which type of upload you want to perform
    GetImage(index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:
                captureImage();
                break;
            case 2:
                getPhoto('pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY');
                break;
            case 3:
                getPhoto('pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM');
                break;

        }

    }
    //// fuction calle from camera capture success
    function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        var i, len;
        debugger;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        }
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function captureError(error) {
        var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
        navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
    }

    //// function to camputure image from camera
    //
    function captureImage() {
        // Launch device camera application, 
        // allowing user to capture up to 2 images
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, capturetError, { limit: 1 });
    }

    //// Upload files to server
    function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        path = mediaFile.fullPath;
        name = mediaFile.name;
////your s url

        var objUrl =www.xyx.com;         

        ft.upload(path,
            objUrl,
            function (result) {
                alert("Success");


            },
            function (error) {
                alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });
    }

    //// fuction to capture image from Gallery or PHOTOLIBRARY
    function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        var cameraSource;
        if (source = "pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY") {
            cameraSource = pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY;
        }
        if (source = "pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY") {
            cameraSource = pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM;
        }

        navigator.camera.getPicture(CaptureImageSuccess, onFail, {

            quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: cameraSource
        });
    }


    //// Upload files to server from Gallery
    function CaptureImageSuccess(fileURI) {
        ////your service url

        var objUrl =www.xyx.com;         

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "file";
            options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)+".jpg";
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            options.params = {}; // if we need to send parameters to the server request
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            //ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI(), win, fail, options);

            ft.upload(fileURI,
                objUrl,
                function (result) {
                    alert("Success");

                },
                function (error) {
                    alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
                },
                options);
    };
```