# How to Open Device Gallery in Android Device using Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, html

I am developing android app using phonegap. i am new for in this technology, i need to upload image from device gallery but select button does not fire on android device. So am using code is given below.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { //image loader
    var uploaderimage = new plupload.Uploader({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5',
        container: 'imagecontainer',
        browse_button: 'pickfiles',
        url: '/imageupload.ashx?mobile=true',
        multi_selection: false,
        max_file_size: '10mb',
        //chunk_size: '1mb',
        multipart: true,
        urlstream_upload: true,
        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [{
            title: "Image files",
            extensions: "jpg,gif,png"
        }]
    });
    uploaderimage.init();
    uploaderimage.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
        //            showmodalmask();
        uploaderimage.start();
        $('.imgpre').show();
        $('.imgcpl').hide();
    });
    uploaderimage.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file) {
        if (uploaderimage.total.uploaded == uploaderimage.files.length) {
            //            $('.btnrefresh').click();
            $('.imgcpl').show();
            $('.imgpre').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My Html code

```
<a id="pickfiles" href="#" style="background-color: #447cd1; color: white; border: 2px solid #113b7c; border-radius: 12px; padding: 6px 10px; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: none">Select file</a>
```

Comment: where you want to upload image on server or in your app @user3273902

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228189/choose-image-from-android-image-gallery-phonegap-not-working) it will help you @user3273902

Comment: Already i have tried this code..,

Comment: Refer - http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Getting-Images-from-Gallery-and-SD-card-in-Smartphones-using-PhoneGap-2259.php

Comment: that code also already i have tried, i getting error some error..,